# How to enable Cloud Pub/Sub API to use it in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

You want to send and consume Cloud Pub/Sub messages from your App Engine application. The Cloud Pub/Sub API is currently disabled. You will use a service account to authenticate your application to the API. You want to make sure your application can use Cloud Pub/Sub. What should
you do?

A. Enable the Cloud Pub/Sub API in the API Library on the GCP Console.

B. Rely on the automatic enablement of the Cloud Pub/Sub API when the Service Account accesses it.

C. Use Deployment Manager to deploy your application. Rely on the automatic enablement of all APIs used by the application being deployed.

D. Grant the App Engine Default service account the role of Cloud Pub/Sub Admin. Have your application enable the API on the first connection to Cloud Pub/Sub.

I realized that if I build an app that uses pubsub. it works without manually enabled the pubsub api. But I couldn't find anything in the documentation about that. Which is the correct answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You want to send and consume Cloud Pub/Sub messages from your App
>   Engine application. The Cloud Pub/Sub API is currently disabled. You
>   will use a service account to authenticate your application to the
>   API. You want to make sure your application can use Cloud Pub/Sub.
>   What should you do?

Let's analyze each possible answer to determine the best answer.

> A. Enable the Cloud Pub/Sub API in the API Library on the GCP Console.

This is a possible answer. The standard method is to enable services in the Google Cloud Console. You can also enable services with the Cloud SDK CLI `gcloud services enable pubsub.googleapis.com`

> B. Rely on the automatic enablement of the Cloud Pub/Sub API when the
>   Service Account accesses it.

This is not a possible answer. Google Cloud Services are not automatically enabled when the service account accesses it. First, service accounts do not access APIs. Service accounts are used to obtain an OAuth Access Token (or Identity Token). These tokens are used to authorize APIs. Services are not automatically enabled with an API makes first access.

> C. Use Deployment Manager to deploy your application. Rely on the
>   automatic enablement of all APIs used by the application being
>   deployed.

This is not a possible answer. Deployment Manager does not automatically enable services. You can use Deployment Manager Resource Types to enable services. You must create a virtual resource for each API that you want enabled.

> D. Grant the App Engine Default service account the role of Cloud
>   Pub/Sub Admin. Have your application enable the API on the first
>   connection to Cloud Pub/Sub.

This is not a possible answer. Cloud Pub/Sub Admin does not have permissions to enable services. To enable services the service account (or User Account) will need `roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageAdmin` or another role with the permission `serviceusage.services.enable`.

**Drumroll Please ....**

Therefore the best answer is A in my opinion.

Comment: But the option A is missin the step of granting the App Engine Service Account access to the Pub/Sub API isn't it?

Comment: @Mauricio - you are correct, but that is not one of the options presented. I think the question is regarding enabling of services and not permissions required to access the service.